# How to make a grid of buttons connected with google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2, google-nearby

I'm trying to make an android application (NearBy places) using google places api and google maps api v2. I'm using [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/) code,it looks good but I want to make a grid of buttons first, and when I click on one of them it show me the nearest places. 
The grid : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE2Oc.png)

How can I change this code to get what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You can make a `frame layout`.. and inside add the map `fragment` and above mao make grid `buttons` as you want .. and per click hide the grid layout .. So the result will show in map and you again load grid layout(Buttons) infront of the Map

Comment: Thank you #Tapan, could you give me an example of a source code to do that !

Comment: You have to do that by your self.. search in google you will get.. Do first as in the website .. Replace 2 buttons with your next grid layout.. Check the image in my answer (What to replace).

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer please mark as a correct answer.